# What kind of adapter should I use to transfer data from a ArrayList to an ListView?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, adapter

I am trying to transfer data from a database to a ListView. Before, I was using a SimpleCursorAdapter to transfer data from a cursor containing all the data, but now, I need to transfer data from five lists into 5 ListViews that I am splitting my cursor into. I don't think I can use an ArrayAdapter because my database has multiple columns. I'm not quite sure how to create my own adapter, though I've read that I could use that. I just don't know how to create my own adapter from BaseAdapter.

### Here is my fragment layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
          /* ....(I skipped much of the irrelevant code here) */
     </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mainList"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/lunchList"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dinnerList"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/snackList"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/exerciseList"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

### Code from Fragment(that I'm currently using to transfer data)

```
    //Append Test Case to Database
    db.createEntry(test);

    //SimpleCursorAdapter Sequence
    cursor = db.getAllEntries();
    String[] from = {DESCRIPTION, CALORIES, SERVINGSIZE, DATE};
    int[] to = {R.id.description, R.id.calories, R.id.servingSize, R.id.dateBox};
    adapt = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.journal_inner_view, cursor,    from, to, 1);
    ListView listItem = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    listItem.setAdapter(adapt);
    //To be implemented for delete and edit commands /*listItem.getOnItemLongClickListener();*/
```

### SQL to Create my Database

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_JOURNAL + " (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " //NON-NLS-1$
                        + JournalDBAdapter.MEAL + " TEXT, " //NON-NLS-1$
                        + JournalDBAdapter.DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, " //NON-NLS-1$
                        + JournalDBAdapter.DATE + " TEXT, " //NON-NLS-1$
                        + JournalDBAdapter.CALORIES + " INTEGER, " //NON-NLS-1$
                        + JournalDBAdapter.SERVINGSIZE + " INTEGER" //NON-NLS-1$
                        + " );"); //NON-NLS-1$ //NON-NLS-2$);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a `CustomAdapter` that extends `ArrayAdapter` in my app for this purpose.

Check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll use something like this for my app. The article helped a lot. I can't vote up your answer because I don't have enough reputation yet but I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, store the results from your database into an arraylist of objects. Use array adapter to add these to your list view. I can't think of an easier way...

Comment: But, how do I add each different values stored in an object to different parts of the inner list. So each of my objects are called entries. And they store like four strings and an int. How do I set each these values to an element of the inner listview?

Comment: To quote an article I found:  "The ArrayAdapter class can handle any Java object as input. It maps the data of this input to a TextView in the layout. You can define one in the constructor otherwise the android.R.id.text1 ID will be used.

ArrayAdapter uses the toString() method of the data input object to determine the String which should be displayed." I don't want to use a string and set all the values to one textview that is multiplied to create the listView. I want an inner view with multiple text views and each value set to one of them. It makes the list View more customizable

Comment: Well yes you need a custom adapter for that and to have each text view filled with different text you need to use objects. Here is the site I used to learn how. It works great. http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/05/03/android-putting-custom-objects-in-listview/